# SUM(quantity) 00:00 - 23.59 Yesterday

Tags: mysql

Based on this how do I make an interval for entire day 00:00 - 23.59 ( Yesterday )

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
    FROM downloads
WHERE
  date>=CURRENT_DATE()
  AND date<CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it-

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
    FROM downloads
WHERE
  date>=CONCAT(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),' 00:00:00')
  AND date<= CONCAT(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),' 23:59:59')
```

or you can use-

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
    FROM downloads
WHERE
  date>=SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND date< CURDATE();
```

Comment: it will use index if there is on date field and perform better we can also use date(date)=subdate(curdate(), interval 1 day) but it will not use index.

Comment: Perfect, both versions display the proper SUM. Thank you

Comment: you may choose it accepted answer by green stick if it helps you... :)

Comment: I know, I did it right now, unfortunately I need to wait few minutes in order to do that :) . Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
    FROM downloads
WHERE
  date = DATE_sub(date,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

For more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add